# NoMethodError - new since upgrading to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm at my wit's end. I upgraded to Rails 4.2.10, and everything is terrible.

Here is the relevant part of /models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate_attributes :price, :is_master, :to => :master
```

And here is /models/variant.rb:

```
class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
```

The variants table has fields for "price" and "is_master". Products table does not.

It used to be the case that one could access Product.price and it would get/set the price for the master variant (there's really only one variant per product, the way things are currently set up).

Now it complains that:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `price=' for #<Product:0x0000000d63b980>
```

It's true. There's no method called price=. But why wasn't this an issue before, and what on earth should I put in that method if I create it?

Here's the code to generate a product in db/seeds.rb:

```
  product = Product.create!({
    name: "Product_#{i}",
    description: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    store_id: u.store.id,
    master_attributes: {
      listing_folder_id: uuids[i],
      version_folder_id: uuids[i]
    }
  })

  product.price = 10
  product.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delegate_attributes` isn't a Rails method and looks like it comes from a gem (or gems) that aren't actively maintained?

If there's a new version of whatever gem you're using that might help, because the short answer is that part of the "delegating" of an attribute would involve getting *and* setting the attribute, so it would generate `#price=` for you.

If you want to define it yourself, this should do it (within your `Product` class):

```
def price=(*args)
  master.price=(*args)
end
```

or if you want to be more explicit:

```
def price=(amount)
  master.price = amount
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Comment: The gem in question is (I believe) active_tools. Maybe something isn't playing nicely together.

Comment: This works for price, but if I try to set is_master the same way, I get "stack level too deep." Hm.