# undefined method `is_master=' for #<Product:0x0000000b8d5300>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Building off of this question/answer: [NoMethodError - new since upgrading to Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953995/nomethoderror-new-since-upgrading-to-rails-4)

Here is the relevant part of /models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate_attributes :is_master, :to => :master

   has_one :master,
  -> { where(["variants.is_master = ? AND variants.deleted_at IS NULL", true]) },
          :class_name => 'Variant',
          :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :master, allow_destroy: false
```

And here is /models/variant.rb:

```
class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  scope :master, -> { where(["variants.is_master = ? AND variants.deleted_at IS NULL", true]) }
```

Currently I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_master=' for #<Product:0x0000000d63b980>
```

This didn't used to be a problem, prior to upgrading to Rails 4, because delegate_attributes should be handling it. The gem delegate_attributes is deprecated, but the methods have been moved into active_tools, which I have installed. But clearly something is still broken, so I have to work around it.

I solved a similar problem with price by:

```
def price=(amount)
  master.price = amount
end
```

But when I try to do the same with is_master:

```
def is_master=(bool)
   master.is_master = bool
end
```

I get the error that `stack level too deep.` Which I can kind of see why, if master.is_master is calling the method is_master over and over, but I wonder why this wasn't an issue with price.

This is where `is_master` is called, in /models/product.rb, but it's not inside `Class Products`.

```
module ProductConcerns
  module Callbacks
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      before_create :set_master_variant_defaults
    end

    def set_master_variant_defaults
       self.is_master = true
    end
  end
end
```

Stack trace:

```
undefined method `is_master=' for #<Product:0x0000000c3bb378>
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.10/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
/pwd/app/models/product.rb:874:in `set_master_variant_defaults'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in `create_or_update'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:487:in `block in save!'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:502:in `block (2 levels) in around_save'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:150:in `block in run_actions'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:170:in `catch_exceptions'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:148:in `run_actions'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:133:in `run_callbacks'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:212:in `run_callbacks'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `catch'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block in perform'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:186:in `within_transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/transition_collection.rb:62:in `perform'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:502:in `block in around_save'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:530:in `block in transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:529:in `transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:501:in `around_save'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/state_machine-1.2.0/lib/state_machine/integrations/active_record.rb:487:in `save!'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/protected_attributes-1.1.4/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/validations.rb:17:in `create!'
/pwd/db/seeds.rb:112:in `block in create_merchant_with_listed_product'
/pwd/db/seeds.rb:110:in `times'
/pwd/db/seeds.rb:110:in `create_merchant_with_listed_product'
/pwd/db/seeds.rb:201:in `block in <top (required)>'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/pwd/db/seeds.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:253:in `load_seed'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:132:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you include the part of *product.rb* that defines `:master`

Comment: I think I've added what you're looking for? (The `scope` line under Variants)

Comment: It helps but is not what I was looking for. The missing part is how you associate Product with Variant, you are doing `delegate_attributes :is_master, :to => :master`. So what i'm looking for is the definition of `:master` in Product.  Also it would be helpfull if you include the stack trace

Comment: Ok, I've updated the post.

Comment: Rails provides a [delegate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) class method to expose contained objects public methods as your own. Maybe you could try with it instead of `delegate_attributes`

Comment: Yeah, I did try that. I should have mentioned. All the same errors.